# ui-bootstrap modal html created and loaded, but isn't shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, showmodaldialog

I'm trying to display a simple modal using ui-bootstrap.

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the html for the modal is loaded but not displayed.

I saw some similar questions on the forum:

- [AngularJS bootstrap.ui modal not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255347/angularjs-bootstrap-ui-modal-not-showing)
- [ui.bootstrap modal loading html but not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952510/ui-bootstrap-modal-loading-html-but-not-showing-anything)

I already did what it was suggested there, but still none improvement.

I updated my libraries and now, I'm using:

- angular: 1.4.9
- angular-animate: 1.4.9
- ui-bootstrap: 1.1.1
- bootstrap.css: 3.6.6

but it didn't helped me.

Also I modified the `bootstrap.css` like it was proposed in another post:

```
modal {
    display: none; to display: block;
}
```

but this didn't also helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by changing the modal jade from

```
div.modal.fade
  div.modal-dialog
    div.modal-content
      div.modal-header
        button.close(type = 'button', data-dismiss = 'modal', aria-hidden = 'true') &times;
        h4.modal-title test
      div.modal-body
        h4 test
      div.modal-footer
       h1 test
```

to

```
div.modal-content
   div.modal-header
     button.close(type = 'button', data-dismiss = 'modal', aria-hidden = 'true') &times;
     h4.modal-title test
   div.modal-body
     h4 test
   div.modal-footer
     h1 test
```