# Trying to show a modal popup but getting this error [$injector:unpr] in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, popup, modal-dialog

Hi I am a newbie and I am learning angularjs. I am implementing a modal popup on click. But seems like there is an issue in dependency.

My index file

```
    <body>
            <div class="global-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 login">
                        <h1 class="align-cent">ShopOber</h1>
                        <div ng-controller="PosController">

<button ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-warning">Simple Popup</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    </body>
    </html>
```

my controller file

```
var posControllers = angular.module('posControllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
posControllers.controller('PosController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$modal', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $modal) {

        $scope.open = function () {
            console.log('opening pop up');
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'popup.html',
            });
        };

    }]);
```

and my app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
     'ngRoute', // we are telling angular that we are using ngRouting feature that enables deeplinking first
    'posControllers',

    // we specify the JS that will handle this module
//'caControllers'
]);
```

Full error in console

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uimodalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uimodal%20%3C-%20PosController
L/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:6:416
eb/q.$injector<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:40:307
d@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:38:308
eb/u.$injector<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:40:379
d@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:38:308
e@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:39:64
Xe/this.$get</</<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:80:149
K@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:61:140
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:326
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349
g@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:54:349
V/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:53:388
yc/d/</<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:20:4
kf/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:35
kf/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:264
yc/d/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:477
e@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:39:94
yc/d@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:398
yc@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:20:179
Zd@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:1
@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:292:238
a@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:174:283
Hf/c@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js:35:124
"
```

I am following this tutorial `https://www.formget.com/angularjs-popup/`.The pop up does not show up although it code does and when i write display:block in console the pop up does come

[image]

My popup.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Popup example with close button
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"
            ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add error stacktrace here in question?

Comment: errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uimodalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uimodal%20%3C-%20PosController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced the library for angular-bootstrap

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
```

also module should be like this,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
     'ngRoute', 
    'posControllers',
    'caControllers',
     'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

[`DEMO`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sajeetharan/8yvb8jt2/)

Comment: by using your method the error goes away but the popup is not showiing

Comment: even the background color does change but the pop up box does not appear

Comment: check the demo app

Comment: I saw it and even mine code is working too in console i checked it it does render the templateurl but the pop up box is not showing

Comment: your answer helped half and this answer helped me half too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952510/ui-bootstrap-modal-loading-html-but-not-showing-anything

Answer (score 1):

Since angular-bootstrap `1.0.0` newer version all the directive & services are prefixed with `uib`. Specifically service are prefixed with `uib` such as `$modal`=> `$uibModal` & directives are prefixed with `uib-` such as `popover` => `uib-popover` .Here you can see the [**changelog**](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6)

So you should be injecting `$uibModal` instead of `$modal`

```
var posControllers = angular.module('posControllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
posControllers.controller('PosController', 
 ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$uibModal',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $uibModal) {
        $scope.open = function() {
            console.log('opening pop up');
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'popup.html',
            });
        };

    }
 ]
);
```

Comment: see the above picture can you help me with this ?

Comment: added check above

Comment: @UsmanIqbal could you check `z-index` please? I guess CSS is messing up

Comment: z-index is set to 1050 you can see inthe image too